# How to set dhclient options for Networkmanager

Tags: fedora, dhcp, networkmanager

I'm trying to modify the domain search order that is obtained via DHCP *a la* `dhclient.conf`:

```
append domain-search "example.com";
```

I'm using Fedora 17 (beta) and it uses `NetworkManager`.  It builds a file `/var/run/nm-dhclient-INTERFACE.conf` which it then calls as the config file for `dhclient`.  My question is, how do I get `NetworkManager` to insert my line into that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit (or create) `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-<device>.conf` and add the line

```
append domain-search "example.com";
```

Comment: This works in the narrow case of the OP's specific dhclient declaration. It should be noted that this will not generally work. NetworkManager uses the values in `dhclient*.conf` as defaults and will override them in some cases (eg. `send host-name`) and will ignore some declarations and blocks (eg.`script`).

Comment: Doesn’t work any more in the year 2021.

Answer (score 1):

In fedora 19 I was able to do this by editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[network name here]` and adding a line at the end that said:

```
DOMAIN=my.domain.com
```

It automatically restarted the connection when I saved and everything.